# Google sheets; check boxes with an "if statement"

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, checkbox, conditional-formatting

I'm working on a record keeping system for the animal room in our small museum using google sheets.  Some of our animals eat every other day.

I have a function that puts the date at the top of the daily sheet.  I need a function which will look at the date and show a checkable box if it's an even date or a line if it's an odd date (or vice versa).  But I can't get the check box into the "or" function.

Super grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(A1); "☑"; "☒")
```

[image]

---

### update:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### [workaround demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cRv1Eqj--QLKIk5KUJmQxmv4l8olPfPnqg7ytxDM5zg/copy)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm so sorry if I wasn't clear - I need a "checkable" box or a line thru the cell.  So, for example, whoever is feeding our animals knows it's not a feeding day (when there"s a line), or can check the box off when feeding is complete (on feeding days)

Comment: @Allison can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I think?  LOL. I'm not used to google docs entirely yet.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k2WPPqjpdLFNOwAPoyyHefc351v7lN-6nLs8ll9TcJc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So, for example, if you look at the groundhogs line, they have a check box for water every day.  Under "clean", depending on the day of the week, it says either "complete" or "partial".  I'd like the food box to either have a check box in it or a line thru it like the one in the ferret's box, depending on the day (although for the record, ferrets and groundhogs do eat every day, lol)

Comment: @Allison the only way how to do this as you imagine would be with the script. the non-scripted workaround I can think of requires merged cells and conditional formatting set to white if the adjacent cell is not empty. see the updated answer

Comment: I'm having a horrible time copying the into another sheet or cell.  Is there a trick I don't know?

Comment: @Allison if you mean conditional formatting rules, then you can just change E6 for E6:E to  apply it for all rows. otherwise its just ctrl+c / ctrl+v or ctrl+alt+v to copy only formatting

Comment: I feel like I tried both those, but will try again.  What you gave me was just conditional formatting rules, correct?  There's nothing else to copy?

Comment: @Allison yes, only those were given. there is no hidden formula

Comment: Is there more than this - =D6<>""  ?  I feel like there should be.  But I'm not seeing it in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @Allison there isnt. even if you change the range of conditional formatting from E6 to E6:E the rule =D6<>"" wont change. the way conditional formating works it will run automatically on all row in providen range where D6 is starting point so even if there is no mention of lets say D10 it will still run as long as row of D10 eg. 10th row is included in selected range E6:E